# how to make working search.php?search=food and search?search=food

Tags: php, url-rewriting

execute php script with and with out '.php' extension

Comment: What do you need to 'handle', what are you thinking htaccess is going to do for you? A little more explanation needed please.

Comment: I wanted to handle GET request parameters in the URL..I have edited my question to simplest form...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a .htaccess file and write a rule like this:

> RewriteRule search.php search

Hope this help

Comment: it worked.Thanks Ollie.but how can i do it on (local) wamp server.